# How do I use the Root External 2 Internal SD app on a Galaxy S4 device?

Tags: internal-storage, root-access

[This app](http://androidforums.com/rush-all-things-root/739747-mod-app-swap-external-sd-internal-mempry.html)

I want to install Dragon Quest VIII, but Google Play automatically downloads straight to the internal storage.

I tried using /mnt/shell/emulated/0 for the internal mount path, and /mnt/extSdCard for the external, but no luck. I also tried [this post](http://androidforums.com/rush-all-things-root/739747-mod-app-swap-external-sd-internal-mempry.html), but there's no "download settings" option for me.

Did I pick the wrong folder paths? If so, how do I find them? The developer's instructions are pretty awful and don't explain half of the options in the app.

I'm on an S4 with Jellybean, rooted. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

How about exchanging ORIGINAL mnt/sdcard to mnt/extsdcard, then ORIGINAL mnt/extsdcard to mnt/sdcard. I am trying to say is swap these two.change their paths so that the phone will read the external as sd card main, and the changed path sd card will be the external memory. Sometime back from MSDOS, if you want to change paths, simply exchanging it's location to execute faster. Maybe my kind of idea will give you an extra help. i hope.

Answer (score 0):

(Rooted Phones Only!) Your Samsung phone is rooted right? You can swap your external to internal just one click from your fingertips without having a sweat. Try to read this information from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.swapit.expander.de , i hope i answered correctly your question on this matter. Thank you.